# Add sqlite entry Using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I am running a simple code here to insert a set of entries in a sqlite table.

```
class MyDB extends SQLite3
{

        function __construct()
        {
                $this->open('new_test.db');
        }
}

        echo "opened database succesfully";

$db = new MyDB();
$db->exec("INSERT INTO RECORDSS(ID,NAME,DEVICE,PROJECT,IP,COMMENT) VALUES('$id','$name','$device','$project','$ip','$comment');");
 $ret = $db->exec($sql);
   if(!$ret) {
        echo "No error in if statement";
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
```

The program executes without any error. However when I open the data base. I see no entries in the table.
What I am doing wrong here ?

Here is my code to view the table.

```
   class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct() {
         $this->open('new_test.db');
      }
   }

   $db = new MyDB();
 $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * from RECORDSS;
EOF;

   $ret = $db->query($sql);
echo "<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
        <th> ID </th>
        <th> NAME </th>
        <th> DEVICE </th>
        <th>PROJECT </th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>COMMENT</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
    {
            echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['ID']. "</td>" ;
                    echo "<td>" . $row['NAME']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['DEVICE']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['PROJECT']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['IP']. "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['COMMENT']. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
    }
       echo "Operation done successfully";
       $db->close();
    echo "</table>"
```

Couple of things that I have checked.

1. The table and database are created, in the same directory with executable permissions.
2. Tried to replace PHP function with python, to achieve the same objective.

Do I have to change something explicitly in the PHP, apache or sqlite Conf files ?

EDIT:- Adding a few details as asked in the comments:

SCRIPT:
called using `<form action ="add_info.php" method="get">`
The form contains:

```
`Name
<input type ="text" name ="name"/>
<br/>
Project
<input type ="text" name ="device"/>
<br/>
`
Not pasting all form fields to make it readable. They are similar.
```

PHP gets the variable as

```
$name= $_GET['name']
```

OS: Uuntu 16.04 server

FIle: All scripts stored under /var/www/html

I dont exactly know about 'file systems'

Comment: Where and how do you populate the variables you're using in your insert?

Comment: And check your http servers error log file for hints, in case you execute that php script in a web environment.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson An HTML form takes these entries and sends to the PHP file using GET method. I printed the variables before using them in the database they are received correctly

Comment: @arkascha thanks, the log file helped, it says unable to open database file. Is looks like permission issue. Is there something to enable apart from making database file executable

Comment: Do _not_ make that file executable! Instead check what user account the http server is executed under and take care that this account has read and write permissions for the file itself _and for the containing folder_! Typically that is done using user group permissions on file system level, so a mask of `0664`.

Comment: Your code is not written that well. For example the message "opened database successfully" is printed anyway, no matter if the DB is really opened or not. Also, you're not safe to SQL injection at all (http://bobby-tables.com to learn how to prevent them).

Comment: @arkascha the user executing PHP is root. I gave the folder read and write permissions. Still the same issue

Comment: That sounds strange (beside the security implications). If the script logs errors into the http servers error log file then I would expect it to be executed under some http server. In that case the script certainly will _not_ be executed under the user account `root` (unless you really borked up your system...). What makes you sure that is the case? Did you check your process table?

Comment: @arkascha I am using the 'get_current_user()' function in PHP to get the user.

Comment: How is that script executed? Please describe your setup in a few words: OS platform, file system hierarchy, environment, request. Add those details to the question above, not in a comment here. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha Done.

Comment: Under Ubuntu the apache http server (usually) is executed under the www-data account. Please take a look into your process table, something like `ps aux|grep apache`. That will tell you the user account the http server process is executed under. That is what you are interested in. You probably want to adjust your file system permissions accordingly: assign the ownership of file and containing folder to the user group `www-data` and make both read- and writeable for that group: `chown root:www-data .....` and `chmod g+rw .....`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
The issue was because of file permissions and ownership.
The apache process was run by user  `www-data`. My files were were run under `root`. Hence giving write permissions to root did not help.
Here is what I did.
change the user of the directory to `www-data` using `chown -hR www-data /var/www/html`.
Gave read and write permissions to the database and PHP file.

Thanks for all the helpful comments.